# Set builder notation for the set of perfect squares

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm trying to express the set of nonzero perfect squares (i.e. $\{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, \dots\}$) using set builder notation.

My attempt:

$$\{x \mid \sqrt{x} \in \mathbb Z^*\}$$

where $\mathbb Z^*$ denotes the set of integers *excluding* $0$.

However, the solution given by my textbook is as follows:

$$\{x^2 \mid x \in \mathbb N\}$$

I'm not sure why the author chose $\mathbb N$ as the domain. The author had previously defined $\mathbb N$ as the set of all natural numbers *including* $0$. But the set of nonzero perfect squares does not include $0$, so **wouldn't it be more accurate to say $\{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, \dots\} = \{x^2 \mid x \in \mathbb Z^* \}$?**

Comment: Does the set of perfect squares include zero? I would tend to say so, but it’s a matter of definitions, and everything seems to hinge on that.

Comment: Yes, but the question specifically asks to express the set $\{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, …\}$ using set builder notation.

Comment: My bad, the solution $\{x^2 \mid x \in \mathbb N\}$ is given in a later chapter as a way of expressing the set of perfect squares, not as a solution to the question in my post, which is just the perfect squares excluding $0$. So would I be correct in writing $\{x \mid \sqrt{x} \in \mathbb Z^*\}$ or $\{x \mid \sqrt{x} \in \mathbb Z \land x \neq 0 \}$?

Comment: The main problem with $\{x | \sqrt x \in \Bbb Z^*\}$ is that there's no indication what set $x$ is supposed to be taken from. It's better not to make the reader guess at our intentions.

Comment: I agree with Greg, it's awkward at best. You could do $\{\,x^2\mid x\in\mathbb{N}-\{0\}\,\}$ instead.

Comment: Ah great point, thank you @GregMartin.

Comment: Thanks @blargoner, I wasn't familiar with $- \{ 0 \}$. Would $\{x^2 \mid x \in \mathbb N \land x \neq 0 \}$ have been acceptable too?

Answer (score 2):

$\{(x+1)^2 \mid x \in \mathbb N\}
$

Comment: Of course! Thank you :)